# Is it true that "do ... done" blocks in Bash do not end with "od" because od existed before Bash/Bourne shell?

Tags: history, unix, shell

The Wikipedia page about [od](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Od_(Unix)&oldid=1013786042#Overview) says:

> Since it predates the Bourne shell, its existence causes an inconsistency in the `do` loop syntax. Other loops and logical blocks are opened by the name, and closed by the reversed name, e.g. `if ... fi` and `case ... esac`, but `od`'s existence necessitates `do ... done`.

Is this really the reason why `do` loops end with `done`?

Comment: The title mentions Bash, but the question seems to be about the (much older) Bourne shell.

Comment: It looks like you've just answered your own question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, certainly. the method of bracketing control structures used in the Bourne Shell was ripped straight from [Algol 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68), in which loop “bodies” were enclosed between **`do`** and **`od`**.

This is a quote about it (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)):

> Stephen Bourne's coding style was influenced by his experience with the ALGOL 68C compiler[2] that he had been working on at Cambridge University. In addition to the style in which the program was written, Bourne reused portions of ALGOL 68's `if ~ then ~ elif ~ then ~ else ~ fi`, `case ~ in ~ esac` and `for/while ~ do ~ od`" (using `done` instead of `od`) clauses in the common Unix Bourne shell syntax.

Comment: Bash was designed to be compatible with Bourne shell. And Bourne shell ripped the control structures from Algol 68

Comment: @DungSaga You're right.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I hope you don't mind when I edited it to add a quote from wikipedia.

Comment: Bourne's pseudo-Algol C code used `od`: https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/mac.h

Comment: @DungSaga Why would someone come to ask questions or read answers here if it’s just quotes from Wikipedia? I’d just go to Wikipedia.

Comment: @texdr.aft Great! What are these `#define` used for?

Comment: @user3840170 I guess because this page saves time and prevent the risk of getting lost while wandering to the Wikipedia forest ;D BTW I like the thoughts you put in your user description, such as: *The best questions are atomic, focused on a single problem. The worst questions are those that require untangling several layers of confusion.*

Comment: A more direct suggestion that the program `od` prevented the use of `od` as a keyword can be found (sans citation) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_(Unix).

Comment: `ENDSW` instead of `HCTIWS` - what was SRB thinking??!

Comment: @DungSaga, ...it's a bit more indirect than that. bash isn't compatible with Bourne -- rather, it's compatible with POSIX sh. The POSIX sh standard definitely has a huge amount of Bourne influence, but compatible they're not -- for example, in true Bourne shell, `^` is a secondary pipe character, whereas it doesn't work that way in either POSIX sh or bash. There's an argument to be made that the POSIX sh standard was more closely drawn from ksh, which was modeled off Bourne...

Comment: @charles-duffy I heard that Bash was designed to be a free software replacement for Bourne shell. and Bash syntax is a superset of Bourne shell syntax. That's why I think Bash is compatible with Bourne shell. But I may be wrong :D
PS: Charles Duffy, your avatar is so cool. it's symmetric calligraphy.

Comment: @toby-speight Maybe he started to feel the awkwardness of typing a long word in reverse. A short word is easier to recognize, even when it's written backward. That could be the reason why he used `CASE/ESAC` instead of `SWITCH/HCTIWS`.

Comment: @DungSaga, try `echo hello ^ cat`. In POSIX sh or bash it outputs `hello ^ cat`; in real original Bourne it outputs just `hello`. (That test is how GNU autoconf distinguishes between original Bourne and POSIX-family shells like ash, dash, or bash).

Comment: @DungSaga, ... remember, original Bourne is a product of the 1970s, whereas POSIX sh was standardized in 1992 (at which time ksh -- from which both bash and the POSIX sh spec drew inspiration -- had substantially improved the state of the art). That's a lot of years for nothing to change; _of course_ a new shell released at the end of the 80s would be more similar to its contemporaries than to something a decade older.